# Integration virtualenvwrapper into Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

There is an option in PyCharm (==2017.2) which allow you to create virtual environments without the CLI.

But this option support `virtualenv` package, does PyCharm can support `virtualenvwrapprr` too ?

I asking it for later use in CLI only.

Comment: There is no need. `virtualenvwrapper` is not a replacement for `virtualenv` but a set of convenient shell functions for it. What do you expect PyCharm would do with `virtualenvwrapper`?

Comment: I'd like the option of telling PyCharm to use virtualenvwrapper to activate my virtualenvs so that my postactivate scripts run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @phd says in comments and also as mentioned in virtualenvwrapper docs, virtualenvwrapper includes wrappers for creating and deleting virtual environments and otherwise managing your development workflow. It is somehow created for making virtualenv easier to use.